# Select records with multiple occurrences and any of them meeting another condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
user('id','name')

product('id','user_id','status','created_at')
```

I want to select all users which have more than one `product.status="InActive"` and at least one of the products is older than 7 days e.g `product.created_at < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )`

I have searched many questions here and could not find the solution.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the users for your criteria by using some conditional aggregation like

```
select u.*
from `user` u
join product p on (u.id = p.user_id)
group by u.id
having count(distinct case when p.status='InActive' then p.id end ) > 1
and sum(p.created_at < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ))
```

Count will get you the users who have morethan 1 inactive products and sum will make sure for the other criteria by resulting as a boolean